# Posting to FB group with requests, allow youtube video to load

Tags: python, facebook, python-requests

I made a simple python script that posts a random youtube video and a quote to Facebook group(s).

The problem is, that it doesn't give Facebook the time to load the random video. To be more specific, at the moment the post looks like this:
[image]

But I want it to look like this:
[image]

My current code looks like this (I omitted sensitive data):

```
""" Song of the day script """

import facebook
import os
from pyquery import PyQuery
import requests
import random


class Sofy(object):

    GROUPS = ["123", "123"]
    FB_ACCESS_TOKEN = "123accesstoken"
    PLAYLISTS = ["123youtubeplaylist"]
    VIDEOS = []

    def get_video(self):
        req = requests.get("https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list={}".format(self.PLAYLISTS[0]))
        pq = PyQuery(req.text)

        for video in pq(".pl-video").items():
            self.VIDEOS.append(video.attr("data-video-id"))
        return "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={}".format(random.choice(self.VIDEOS[-5:]))

    def get_qoute(self):
        pwd = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        fx = pwd + '/quotes.txt'
        lines = open(fx).read().splitlines()
        return random.choice(lines)

    def run(self):
        quote = self.get_qoute()
        video = self.get_video()
        graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token=self.FB_ACCESS_TOKEN, version='2.2')

        for group in self.GROUPS:
            graph.put_object(group, "feed", message="{}\n Song of the day: {}".format(quote, video))
        print "All done :)"

if __name__=='__main__':
    sofy = Sofy()
    sofy.run()
```

I tried doing this with `Selenium` but it didn't quote work as expected. Also, this way looks cleaner, but I can't figure out how to let youtube video load, I'm not even sure if it's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're actually sharing the link correctly, looks like you're adding the URL into the 'message' parameter -

It should be attached correctly if you specify it in the 'link' parameter